# inflate footer view is slow

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem using the footer of my list view. In fact, I inflate an xml and I send it to the footerView. When my activity appears, my listview is showing and after two or three seconds (sometimes more) my footer is showing. Why is it so long ?

Here is a part of my code :

```
private View footerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.order_footer_item, null);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

// This is Android annotation
@AfterViews
protected void setAfterViews() {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);

    TextView text = (TextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Test");
    list.addFooterView(footerView);
}
```

I have no problem except slowing. Why ? How can I improve that ?

Thx in advance

Comment: where are you setting the content of the view to the activity and the problem could be in adapter also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it before setting adapter.

```
list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

And then

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Moreover it makes sense adding the footer view before the adapter. Thx

Comment: Thanks, such a simple solution, but when still learning this kind of thing could trip you up for a while.

Answer (score 1):

This was a tricky problem for me. After spending quite a while working on it I realized that I was giving a parent parameter to the `.inflate(view,parent,boolean)` method instead of leaving it as **null** because I handle it with the `getListView().addFooterView()` method.

Error:

```
TextView footerView = (TextView) ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_view, this.getListView(), true);

this.getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

Fix:

```
TextView footerView = (TextView) ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null, false);

this.getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: Why pass null as the parent? Is it a good solution? At least, Eclipse warns you about it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably create the footer view in the `onCreateView`, where you get a `LayoutInflater inflate` and a `ViewGroup container`.

Then, you'd call

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, container, false);
```

And the rest as per vipul mittal solution.